# IdentityServer4 with aspnet identity and JavaScript client

Tags: asp.net-identity, single-sign-on, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I'm trying to implement IdentityServer4. All the clients will be JavaScript app (in react js). My questions are:

1. We will have our custom user database so I'm trying to implement the IS4 with Aspnet identity like the 6th example. But, as my client is JavaScript based, I have to use de implicit flow, and in the example (as it is done with a MVC client) is made with the HybridAndClientCredentials in mind. Also, the MVC Login app doesn't seem to include the consent step. I implemented the JavaScript client example in combination with the AspnetIdentity example. At first it gave me the error:

> IdentityServer4.Validation.ScopeValidator: Error: Invalid scope: api2,

(api2 is the API the client will be calling), but api2 is included in the client definition:

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "js2",
                ClientName = "JavaScript Client 2",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                RequireConsent = true,
                RedirectUris =           { "http://jstwo:5004/callback.html" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://jstwo:5004/index.html" },
                AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "http://jstwo:5004" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api2"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            }
```

Just to try to move on, I removed that scope from the client call, And it worked. I logged in but as the consent step is missing the client crashed.

[image: Error image]

So, I think I'm kind of lost here. Should I find a way to skip the consent step? (it would be good because we don't want that step either way, All users will be internal).

2.- Also we need to persist in the database all the structures like in the sample  8_EntityFrameworkStorage. Can I use this way in combination with AspIdentity?

The samples which are referred to: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples

Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: You should only ask one question per post. And just look at the line `RequireConsent = true`, change it to false and you won't need to do the consent step.

Comment: Sorry, for the two questions. I feel a little silly, it was so simple the skip consent, it worked thank you very much!. but I still don't get why I had to remove the "api2" scope.

Comment: make sure "api2" exists in your api resources in the config file on the server!